# Error when setup SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Today I want setup SQL Server 2017. But it error, have a Message box :"The system cannot find the file specified"

How to fix ?? Thanks

[image: Messagebox]

Some picture:
[image: Picture2]
[image: Picture3]

Comment: DId you click Retry?

Comment: The image of your whole desktop is difficult to read. could you just give us the error window, and its complete text, as well as what stage you were at when it errored?

Comment: Why are you trying to install RC1? Download the RTM version. RC versions are no longer supported and should not be used for Production or Development environments.

Comment: @Larnu: Please the me SQL Server 2014 RTM or SQL Server 2017 RTM

Comment: @dfundako: I did click Retry but nothing change.

Comment: *"Please the me"*? I don't understand what you mean,

Comment: I want link SQL Server 2014 RTM or SQL Server 2017 RTM

Comment: Would suggest to download the installer again from here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50469353/edit) your post, please, don't just post links to off site images in the comments.

Comment: Are those latest images with the RTM release?

Comment: Yes, It's RTM release